# Prove that if $f: A \to B$ is an injective function and $h: A \to C$ is any function, then there always exists a function $g: B \to C$ with $h = g∘f$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm not an incredibly well versed proof writer and I would like some help with this proof. I really want to know if I'm along the right track or if I need to be going in a different direction. The question does not come from our textbook, but we use *A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics* By: Martin Liebeck.

I found a similar question answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065739/suppose-that-f-a-to-b-and-g-b-to-c-are-functions) but, I do not belive the proof is exactly the same. (let me know if this question is answered already and I'll delete the post.)

Here is the question and my proof.

Prove that if $f: A \to B$ is an injective function and $h: A \to C$ is any function, then there always exists a function $g: B \to C$ with $h = g\circ f$.

> Assume for contraduction that $f$ is not an injective function, so $a_{1} \neq a_{2}$ but $f(a_{1}) = f(a_{2})$. Thus $g\circ f = g(f(x))$ and $g(f(a_{1})) = g(f(a_{2}))$, wich cannot happen in a well defined function. Thus a contradiction. Therefore $f$ must be injective for $g$ to exist and be well defined.

Again I really just want to know if I'm going in the right direction and if not point me the right way please.

From what I understand it seems like I might be skipping a few steps on the proof.

Comment: What you have shown is that if $f$ is not injective, then $g \circ f$ is not injective. The function $g \circ f$ can be well defined!

The simplest approach is to prove the existence of $g$ is to define it directly. Here is a hint. 
Define $g(x)$ in two different cases: $x \in f[A]$ and $x \not \in f[A]$.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung could you expand on that a bit I'm still confused, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verv14, what you have proved is that $g \circ f(a_1)=g \circ f(a_2) $. It means that $g \circ f$ maps different $a$ to the same image. This is okay with a function.

What is not allowed for a well-defined function is that it maps an element to 2 different images. This is certainly not the case here. Hence your proof is invalid.

To prove something exists, we usually adopt one of the following strategies: either prove that its non-existence leads to contradiction, or construct it directly.

In the present situation, constructing $g$ would be simplest.

Since the fucntion $g:B \to C$ has to satisfy $g(f(x))=h(x) \forall x \in A$ and $f(x)=y$ for some $y \in B,$ we natually define $g(y)$ by considering whether $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in A$ or not.

Thus if  $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in A$, we define $g(y)$ to be $h(x).$

What is left then is to define $g$ for $y \not =f(x)$ for any $x \in A$. But this is easy.

After defining $g$, we need to show that our $g$ is a well-defined function.

That is,

$(1)$ $g$ is defined for all $y \in B$, and

$(2)$ $g$ will not map one $y$ to 2 different images.

This is where $f$ is injective comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $f$ maps $A$ onto $f[A]$ and so as $f$ is 1-1, it is a bijection from $A$ to $f[A]$. Hence $f$ has an inverse, $f^{-1}$ and $f^{-1}$ maps $f[A]$ to $A$. Define the function $g$ on $B$ by $g(x)=(h\circ f^{-1})(x)$ if $x \in f[A]$ and $c$ if $x \in B\backslash f[A]$, where $c$ is $h(y)$ for some specific $y$ in $A$. Then $g:B \rightarrow C$ and $g \circ f=h$